# JWPlayer How to include multiple video files?

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

How do I include multiple files such that everything appears as one video to the user, in JWplayer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by using a playlist.

Demos:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29253/basic-rss-feed
http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29247/basic-inline-playlist